# stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString not working

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsstring

I want to replace some components  in myurl with some other components, but it is not working..

**Here is my Code snippet:**

```
NSString *Url =@"http://www.myData.com/pageId=aaa&pageSize=bbb&page=2"
```

In above Url i want to replace `aaa` with `str1` and `bbb` with `str2`..

```
    [Url stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"aaa" withString:str1];
    [Url stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"bbb" withString:str2];

    NSLog(@"Final Url = %@",Url);
```

and finally when i see my Log, `Final Url` doesn't replaces `aaa` with `str1` and `bbb` with `str2`..

***Thanks for reading...***

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some string functions take in-place replacements, but others return a replaced one.

Full Code Below :

```
NSString *Url = @"http://www.myData.com/pageId=aaa&pageSize=bbb&page=2";
Url = [Url stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"aaa" withString:str1];
Url = [Url stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"bbb" withString:str2];

NSLog(@"Final Url = %@",Url);
```

Comment: It crahses.. shows `-[NSDecimalNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xab75ad0`

Comment: @Krunal The code is just a snippet, I edited for full version.  -- :)

Comment: @JasonLee What NSString methods do in-place replacement?

Answer (score 13):

The method `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` returns `NSString` and you need to store that one.

You are simply dumping the returned value and expecting the caller to be changed.

You need to use :

```
Url=[Url stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"aaa" 
                                   withString:str1];
Url=[Url stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"bbb" 
                                   withString:str2];
```

Comment: It crahses.. shows -[NSDecimalNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xab75ad0

Comment: @Krunal: The crasing can't be from this code. Check for other code, where you are using number thinking it as NSString and finding its length!!!

Comment: There are some methods that **modify the object itself** and there are some methods that **return a value**, I believe that is where the OP's confusion came from. Generally is there anything that *categorizes* the difference between these 2 methods?

Answer (score 2):

Use the below code it's working perfectly at my end. I have tested it.

```
NSString *Url =@"http://www.myData.com/pageId=aaa&pageSize=bbb&page=2";
    NSString *str1 = @"str1";
    NSString *str2 = @"str2";

    Url = [Url stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"aaa" withString:str1];
    Url = [Url stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"bbb" withString:str2];

    NSLog(@"Final Url = %@",Url);
```

Output will be : Final Url = http://www.myData.com/pageId=str1&pageSize=str2&page=2

All the best !!!